# There was an error saving changes. Please try again later or contact App Store Developer Support

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

While submitting app information in iTunes am getting following error

The following error(s) occurred:
There was an error saving changes. Please try again later or contact App Store Developer Support.

Does anybody knows that why this error is occurring ?

Thanks,

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about other site.

Comment: @mani I think that will be next step . but i am getting this error while submitting the information like adding screen shots ,app name ett

Comment: Do as it suggests, contact App Store Developer Support.

Comment: I'll automatically clear after some time. I've seen in many sites. they told like that. Some guy told that, it'd cleared after two days.

Comment: @Gavin  yeah i did this . but in contact also they ask about app ID :)

Comment: @Mani . I changed three systems and browsers also . trying since my morning :(

Comment: Same happening at me. I've tried with three different iTunes Connect accounts, none of them works. I think this is a serious issue, but Apple seems to ignore it: https://developer.apple.com/support/system-status/

Comment: here i got reply from Apple :

We are aware of an issue with our system that is preventing our developers from accessing some features of iTunes Connect. Our engineers are working to resolve this issue as soon as possible. Please continue to check iTunes Connect over the next 24 hours for any functionality that might return.

Lets see how early they fix it

Comment: I have sent mail to apple that includes error screen shot and error-webpage-source code. I am waiting for their reply . Lets see when they will fix this WORLDWIDE issue :) . The same thing I did ask in Raywenderlich forum you can also refer [http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=11203]

Comment: Had this problem too, but now it's working again! Apple's system status is also green for about an hour. https://developer.apple.com/support/system-status/

Comment: Finally its working :)

Comment: I was in a similar situation, had to submit with the same binary version originally as it was a Meta Data error. Even though it allows you and prompts you to submit a newer version.





From Apple: "Since your App Store Connect status is Metadata Rejected, we do NOT require a new binary. To revise the metadata, visit App Store Connect to select your app and revise the desired metadata values. Once you’ve completed all changes, reply to this message in Resolution Center and we will continue the review."